# Conda - unable to completely delete environment

Tags: python, conda

I am using Windows 10 (all commands run as administrator). I created an environment called myenv. Then I used

> conda env remove -n myenv

Now, if I try

> conda info --envs

I only see the base environment. However, if I try

> conda activate myenv

I'm still able to activate it! I think because under the folder envs, there is still a folder with the name myenv there which doesn't get deleted.

How do I delete the environment for good?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Command-line options can only go so far, unless you get very specific; perhaps the simplest approach is to delete things manually:

1. Locate Anaconda folder; I'll use `"D:\Anaconda\"`
2. In `envs`, delete environment of interest: `"D:\Anaconda\envs\myenv"`

Are you done? Not quite; even while in `myenv`, conda will still sometimes install packages to the *base* environment, in `"D:\Anaconda\pkgs\"`; thus, to clean traces of `myenv`,

3. Delete packages installed to `myenv` that ended up in `"D:\Anaconda\pkgs\"`
4. (If above don't suffice) Anaconda Navigator -> Environments -> myenv -> Remove
5. (If above don't suffice) Likely corrupted Anaconda; make note of installed packages, completely uninstall Anaconda, reinstall.

*Note*: step 3 is redundant for the goal of simply removing `myenv`, but it's recommended to minimize future package conflicts.

Comment: "*Delete packages installed to `myenv` that ended up in "D:\Anaconda\pkgs\"*" Oh please no don't do that! That's the package cache that all envs share. No one should be manually doing stuff in there. The `conda clean` command can cover anything that can be safely done in that folder. In this case `conda -p` will remove all packages with no other links.

Comment: @merv It was the only approach that worked for me in clearing up conflicting TF1 vs TF2 versions, along their Keras 2.2.5 & 2.3.0, without reinstalling the entirety of Anaconda - and I faced instances of `conda clean` wiping 1GB+ of packages for no good reason. I did pick words carefully; _"that ended up in"_ - i.e. no more, no less. If you have a yet better alternative in mind, I'll gladly hear it

Comment: The problem I have with this claim is that Conda simply doesn't work in a way consistent with the explanation. Specifically, **no envs directly reference `pkgs`**, including **base**. It is only a cache and installations into envs are achieved by either (hard)linking or copying into the relevant env folders (`lib`, `bin`, `include`, etc). The only exception to this is when users enable softlinks (very rare - usually for spanning volumes), which can lead to problems with `conda clean` because filesystems don't have low-level tracking of the reference count with softlinks.

Comment: @merv It's true I don't know of `conda`'s inner workings on levels you're describing, but I did observe **env conflicts with `pkgs`** - for example, running `conda install keras==2.3.0` would fail to fetch `keras_preprocessing` until I manually removed it from `pkgs` - and that was the only fix I needed, where `conda clean` would be an overkill. Does this sound accurate? I can add a disclaimer to my answer per your comments, but I'd say "no manual ever" is a bit too strict

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the first command in the question posted, I had to complete one additional step to completely remove the environment. I had to go to the folder where the environment was stored (e.g. C:\Users*username*.conda\envs\ on a windows machine) and remove the folder with the same name as the environment I deleted. After this second step, I was able to reuse the environment name without any errors.